# Как вернуть названия всех полей класса?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, рефлексия

Как сделать функцию внутри класса, которая может вернуть энумератор/список  `string` c названиями всех публичных полей этого класса?
Например есть класс:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyField {get; set;}
}
```

В нем определим функцию:

```
public List<string> GetAllField()
{
//
}
```

Суть в том, что бы можно было добавлять поля и не править каждый раз функцию `GetAllField()`

Comment: Что то типа `this.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x=>x.Name)`

Comment: Да это сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользоваться рефлексией и получить данные о полях из самого класса -

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetPublicProperties() {
    return this.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.GetMethod.IsPublic)
        .Select(x => x.Name)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Однако подобный код будет ресурсозатратным, лучше вынести определение полей в 
 статический конструктор класса

```
public class Example
{
    private static readonly string[] _publicProperties;

    static Example()
    {
        _publicProperties = typeof(Example)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.GetMethod.IsPublic)
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToArray();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TestValue { get; set; }
    public string TestValue2 { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetPublicProperties()
    {
        return _publicProperties;
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, только 1 замечание - так как у класса есть и поля и свойства, а вы ещё и только публичные выбираете, то метод лучше назвать `GetPublicProperties()` и приватное поле тоже `_publicProperties`. Ну и если вы хотите сэкономить ресурсы, то воспользуйтесь типом 'Lazy<>', чтобы вычислять поля только 1 рвз и только тогда, когда они запрашиваются.

Comment: Если вам действительно на выходе не нужен массив, то так `.ToArray()` делать не следует, т.к. эта операция вызывает прежде `ToList()`, затем вычисляет кол-во элементов, а затем уже формирует массив на выход. Так что лучше просто `ToList()`